# Program crashing while attempting to only create a form if user logged in

Tags: java, html, sql, forms, jsp

```
                while (rs.next() != false){%>
                    ID: <%= rs.getString(1) %>
                    PRODUCT: <%= rs.getString(2) %>
                    DESCRIPTION: <%= rs.getString(3) %> <br>
                    SOLD BY: <%= rs.getString(4) %> <br>
                    Listed: <%= rs.getString(5) %>
                    Ends: <%= rs.getString(6) %><br>
                    Current Bid: $<%= rs.getString(7) %>
                     <%if (session.getAttribute("loggedIn") == "true"){
                         out.println("place bid:");
                         %> <form method="bid.jsp" action = "get"><input form = "text" name = "newBid"> </form><%
                     }%>
                <%}
```

The idea is that it outputs the whole table, with each row being a different auction item, though the ability to bid on said item is intended to only be available to logged in users.

I was thinking that I could output the table and before a form that allows the user to bid, to check if they had logged in, which is stored in the session variable "loggedIn".

Though it causes the program to crash, saying that I need a ';', ')' or '}'. But I don't know where I would put one.

Comment: Why the <sql> tag? (I see no SQL there.)

Comment: avoid scriptlets in your jsps

Comment: I think,  the last <%} should be  }%>.

Comment: please provide some more information